# Http Reponse: Cannot Authenticate, what code?

Tags: asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

What http code should i respond with if I cannot find a user in the database and therefore, cannot authenticate him.

I personally do not like like idea of returning 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend either 401 or 403 .404 is not found which could be also because resource is not available even user is authenticated. Ref [Standard Error Code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

401 Unauthorized, the HTTP status code for authentication errors. And that’s just it: it’s for authentication, not authorization. Receiving a 401 response is the server telling you, “you aren’t authenticated–either not authenticated at all or authenticated incorrectly–but please reauthenticate and try again.” To help you out, it will always include a WWW-Authenticate header that describes how to authenticate.